# Facing error with "lpcap not found" although I have already installed libpcap

Tags: go, gcc, makefile, pcap

Facing error with `cannot find lpcap` for make command for some package, although I have already installed `libpcap-devel`.

```
go build -i -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags -static -X main.version=git-6e3f8a1c7a0a" -tags netgo -o prog/weaver/weaver ./prog/weaver
# github.com/weaveworks/weave/prog/weaver
/go/pkg/tool/linux_s390x/link: running s390x-linux-gnu-gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/lib64/gcc/s390x-suse-linux/7/../../../../s390x-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap
/tmp/go-link-225248852/000015.o: In function `mygetgrouplist':
/tmp/workdir/go/src/os/user/getgrouplist_unix.go:15: warning: Using 'getgrouplist' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

I can see the .so files at

```
 /usr/lib64 # ls | grep pcap
 libpcap.so
 libpcap.so.1
 libpcap.so.1.8.1
```

Comment: Are you cross compiling for a IBM zSeries?

Comment: I am running on IBM z vm

Comment: Can you see the .a file? Shared libraries are not relevant for static linking.

Comment: made another suggestion.... hope that it makes sense (and works)

Comment: I didnot find .a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [openSUSE `libpcap` development RPm](https://software.opensuse.org/package/libpcap-devel)
does not provide a static `libpcap.a`, so you cannot statically link `libpcap` unless you
are able to build the static library from source (and any others to which the same applies).

Removing `-static` from your `-ldflags` would avoid this problem, if it is an option for you
to link your go program dynamically.

Comment: or install from source

Answer (score 0):

Install the devel version of the library and you get the headers and the .a files as well as the .so shared libraries

The C linker needs these for static linking

Also, the build process needs to be able to find the .a files.  This should happen automatically but you can help it

Find the directory that the .a files are in ( for instance by listing the package you used to install ) and add that directory with a -L option in your ldflags

Comment: I did installed the libpcap devel. Still facing same issue.